# vagrant: can I `vagrant up` just one machine from multi-machine setup

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

can I `vagrant up` just one machine from multi-machine setup?

or

how could I have different setups for developing e.g. `local`, `test` and `production`? do I have to have different `Vagrantfile`s?

example `Vagrantfile` (taken from Multi-Machine Doc page)

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo Hello"

  config.vm.define "web" do |web|
    web.vm.box = "apache"
  end

  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.box = "mysql"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To start desired machine just call `vagrant up machine_name`.
   In your config it could be `vagrant up web`.

By setting `autostart: false` in machine configuration, you block autostart of the machine in `vagrant up` call. More about vagrant multi-machine configuration [here](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/).

2.There are many ways to have different setups in vagrant.

a. Define different machines with different provisions scripts :

```
  config.vm.define "m1", autostart: false do |m1|
    m1.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
        s.path = "path_to/m1_provision_script.sh"
    end
  end 
  config.vm.define "m2", autostart: false do |m2|
    m2.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
        s.path = "path_to/m2_provision_script.sh"
    end
  end
```

b. Provide different parameter to provision script:

```
  config.vm.define "m1", autostart: false do |m1|
    m1.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
        s.path = "path_to/provision_script.sh"
        s.args = "machine_1"
    end
  end 
  config.vm.define "m2", autostart: false do |m2|
    m2.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
        s.path = "path_to/provision_script.sh"
        s.args = "machine_2"
    end
  end
```

c. If you are using puppet as a provisioner, you can also define custom fact the will indicate if machine is `local`, `test` or `prod`.